# Exchange 2010 room calendar don't show appointment body/description

Tags: exchange-2010, configuration, calendar

When a user books an appointment in Outlook, and adds a room resource, the room auto-attendant accepts the meeting.  However, the meeting in the room calendar does not show the body/description portion of the meeting that the user entered.

Other users see the body/description portion fine, but it is not in the room calendar.

The room's copy of the appointment is used by a 3rd party package for other processing, and needs access to the body/description.

Is there a way to have the body/description appear properly in the rooms copy of the appointment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Exchange Management Console, open the properties for this particular room, and check the Resource Information tab. Check to make sure that the "Delete comments" box is not selected.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.  One of those classic, "where did they hide this" questions.